# how many emails does my mac book air archive hold?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mail.app

I am saving emails in the archive option on my  macbook air.

What is the quantity limit??

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll [reach a limit](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201711).

HFS+ which stores the file limits you to 2.1 billion files in a folder so you could have a lot of emails stored to archive. When you go to archive them, that one file holding billions of messages could grow to a size of 8 EB (and one exabyte is one million terabytes) so there's really little chance Mail app will prevent you from archiving an absurdly silly number of messages.